# Checkbox.Ischecked always gives false

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

My checkbox is always returning false. Can some one please help me.This is my html div.

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <label for="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary">
        <input class="toggle_enabled hidden-field" id="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary" name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="true" type="checkbox">
        <span class="custom checkbox"></span>
        <input name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="false" type="hidden">IsPrimary
    </label>
</div>
```

When the checkbox is checked, the page inspector code shows the following html snippet

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <label for="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary">
        <input class="toggle_enabled hidden-field" id="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary" name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="true" type="checkbox">
        <span class="custom checkbox checked"></span>
        <input name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="false" type="hidden">IsPrimary
    </label>
</div>
```

When the checkbox is NOT checked, the page inspector code shows the following html snippet

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <label for="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary">
        <input class="toggle_enabled hidden-field" id="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary" name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="true" type="checkbox">
        <span class="custom checkbox"></span>
        <input name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="false" type="hidden">IsPrimary
   </label>
</div>
```

My data variable in jQuery code is giving isPrimary = false in both case.

```
var data =
    {
        customerGuid: $("#Data_CustomerGuid").val(),
        contactInfoType: type,
        contactInfo: $("#Data_AlternatePhones_"+i+"__PhoneNumber").val(),
                isPrimary: $("#Data_AlternatePhones_" + i + "__IsPrimary").is(':checked'), 
    isPrimaryTest: $("#Data_AlternatePhones[" + i + "]_IsPrimary > span").is(':checked'),                  
        contactInfoID: $("#Data_AlternatePhones_"+i+"__ID").val()
    };
```

[Image of the data i get in the developer tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7yVu.png)

Please help me figure this out.
Thank you.

This is my actual mark up in my cshtml file.

```
     @if (Model.Data.AlternatePhones.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.AlternatePhones.Take(2).Count(); i++)
            {
                <div style="float:right">
                    <a data-reveal-id="divFirstSetEditAlternatePhoneNumber@(i)" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" data-i="@i" data-contactinfotype="phone" ></a>
                    <a class="fa fa-trash-o deletecontactinfo" data-customer-id="@Model.Data.CustomerGuid" data-info="@Model.Data.AlternatePhones[i].PhoneNumber" data-contactinfotype="phone"></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Model.Data.AlternatePhones[i].PhoneNumber                        
                    @if (Model.Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsVerified)
                    {
                        <div class="fa fa-user"><span class="verified">Verified Customer</span></div><br />
                    }
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="divFirstSetEditAlternatePhoneNumber@(i)" class="reveal-modal tiny" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
                    <div class="form custom med-6 columns popupModal">
                        <h2>
                            Edit Phone Number
                        </h2>
                        <form>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Data.CustomerGuid)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Data.AlternatePhones[i].ID)
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                    @Html.WrappedTextBoxFor(x => Model.Data.AlternatePhones[i].PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "toggle_enabled" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                    @*@Html.WrappedCheckBoxFor(x => Model.Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "toggle_enabled" })*@

                                    <label for="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary">
                                        <input class="toggle_enabled hidden-field" id="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary" name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="true" type="checkbox">
                                        <span class="custom checkbox"></span>
                                        <input name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="false" type="hidden">IsPrimary
                                    </label>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                    <input type="button" class="btnEditAlternatePhoneNumber button toggle_enabled" value="Save" />
                                    <button class="btnCloseEditAlternatePhoneNumber button toggle_enabled closediv">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                                <a class="close-reveal-modal toggle_enabled">&#215;</a>
                            </div>


                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
```

Comment: But i get the correct data for the other properties like customerGuid and contactInfo. Only the checkbox is wrong

Comment: Then can you show us the actual markup cause what you showed us would not match any of those selectors.

Comment: Where are you getting the variable `i`? Also, if that's in a loop, are you intending to overwrite the data object?

Comment: This is the actual markup i have in my cshtml file.

Comment: <label for="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary">
                                            <input class="toggle_enabled hidden-field" id="Data_AlternatePhones[i]_IsPrimary" name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="true" type="checkbox">
                                            <span class="custom checkbox"></span>
                                            <input name="Data.AlternatePhones[i].IsPrimary" value="false" type="hidden">IsPrimary
                                        </label>

Comment: Only the check box is having any issue. Every thing else works fine

Comment: There is one underscore in the ID of html but you are searching for two underscores.

Comment: What's the purpose of that `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

your input element not closed correctly. close input tag.
add **/** to end of your input element